# Testsing mediaplayer with Gitlab CI and Junit

Tags: java, maven, junit, gitlab

I am currently writing tests for an application that can load videos and play/pause them. We are using maven as build framework, and junit as test framework. The test code looks like this:

```
public class UnitTest extends ApplicationTest {

  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;
  @FXML
  private MediaView mediaView1;
  @FXML
  private Button playPauseButton;
  private static Media media;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    try {
      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("videoMain.fxml"));
      stage.setTitle("Vorprojekt");
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1300, 900);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    try {
      media = new Media(getClass().getResource("small.mp4").toString());
      mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer(media);
      mediaView1 = find("#mediaView1");
      mediaView1.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer1);
      playPauseButton = find("#playPauseButton");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
  }

  @Test
  public void playPauseButtonTest() {
    mediaPlayer1.play();
    clickOn(playPauseButton);
    try {
      assertTrue(mediaPlayer1.getStatus().equals(Status.PAUSED));
    } catch (AssertionError ae) {
      fail("Status should be paused but is " + mediaPlayer1.getStatus());
    }

  }
}
```

This tests runs without any problems, if I run it locally on my device. But if I run it on my Gitlab CI , the following Error is thrown:

> [INFO] Running UnitTest [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0,
>   Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.776 s <<< FAILURE! - in UnitTest [ERROR]
>   playPauseButtonTest(UnitTest)  Time elapsed: 1.772 s  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.AssertionError: Status should be paused but is HALTED   at
>   UnitTest.playPauseButtonTest(UnitTest.java:65)
>
> [INFO]  [INFO] Results: [INFO]  [ERROR] Failures:  [ERROR]
>   UnitTest.playPauseButtonTest:65 Status should be paused but is HALTED
>   [INFO]  [ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>   [INFO]  [ERROR] There are test failures.
>
> Please refer to /builds/swp18/tj18a/Code/target/surefire-reports for
>   the individual test results. Please refer to dump files (if any exist)
>   [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
 maven_build:
 image: tomsontom/oracle-java8-mvn
 script:
  - cd Code
  - apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
  - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install openjfx xserver-xorg-   video-dummy xinit fonts-freefont-ttf libavformat-ffmpeg56 wget libswt-gtk-3-java firefox -y
- wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thewtex/docker-opengl/master/etc/X11/xorg.conf -O /etc/X11/xorg.conf
- xinit -- :0 -nolisten tcp vt$XDG_VTNR -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER +extension XFIXES &
- DISPLAY=:0 mvn --batch-mode package
- cd target && ls -la
```

Any ideas how to adjust the code, so the test also works in the gitlab CI?

I'm grateful for every hint, because I have no ideas anymore how to possibly fix it.

Here's the important part of my pom.xml, if you are interested.

```
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
       </configuration>
       <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
       <dependencies>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
           <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
         </dependency>
       </dependencies>
     </plugin>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0</version>
       <configuration>
         <source>8</source>
         <target>8</target>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
There were 2 problems we didn't handle. First of all, the virtual monitor was defined with the size 1366x768, while the user interface was initialized with the size 1300x900. Accordingly the play/pause button couldn't be reached. 
The second fault was , that the mediaplayer needs more time getting initialized in the runner. So after the mediaplayer is initialized, and after the status should swap to playing, a loop is needed to wait for the mediaplayer to swap. The following setup method fixed the problem for us:

```
  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    media = new Media(getClass().getResource("small.mp4").toString());
    mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaPlayer1.setOnError(() -> fail("media error" + mediaPlayer1.getError().toString()));
    int retries = 0;
    while (mediaPlayer1.getStatus() != MediaPlayer.Status.READY) {
      System.out
          .println("media player not yet READY - current status: " + mediaPlayer1.getStatus());
      sleep(100);
      retries++;
      if (retries > 10) {
        fail("waited too long for media player to get READY");
      }   
    }   
    mediaView1 = find("#mediaView1");
    mediaView1.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer1);
    mediaPlayer1.play();
    retries = 0;
    while (mediaPlayer1.getStatus() != MediaPlayer.Status.PLAYING) {
      System.out
          .println("media player not yet PLAYING - current status: " + mediaPlayer1.getStatus());
      sleep(100);
      retries++;
      if (retries > 10) {
        fail("waited too long for media player to get PLAYING");
      }   
    }   
  }
```

And this gitlab ci was needed:

```
maven_build:
  image: tomsontom/oracle-java8-mvn
  script:
    - cd Code
    - apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
    - DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install openjfx xserver-xorg-video-dummy xserver-xorg-input-void xinit fonts-freefont-ttf pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils libavformat-ffmpeg56 wget libswt-gtk-3-java firefox -y
    - wget https://xpra.org/xorg.conf -O /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    - service dbus start
    - xinit -- :0 -nolisten tcp vt$XDG_VTNR -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER +extension XFIXES &
    - DISPLAY=:0 pulseaudio --exit-idle-time=-1 &
    - DISPLAY=:0 mvn --batch-mode package
    - cd target && ls -la
```